# Mark function suspend or using builder

Tags: kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I'm starting with coroutines in Android app. I'm rewriting callbacks to `suspendCoroutine<> {}` and I've got one dillema: when should I just mark the function as `suspend`, and when should I wrap the call in some builder (`launch`, `async`, etc.)?

Is there some best practice, rule of thumb, or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write a `suspend fun` for every asynchronous, callback-based API call you're currently making.

You should wrap in `withContext(myThreadPool)` every synchronous API call you're making.

All Android-friendly APIs that do I/O use the async approach, so for these you'll be writing `suspend fun`s, but for CPU-intensive tasks (such as decoding images) you may need `withContext`.

Finally, to be able to use either kind of calls, you must create a top-level coroutine with `launch(UI)`.

---

Keep in mind that the above is really just a rule of thumb. When you factor your code, many times you realize you need, for example, a `suspend fun` to make a CPU-intensive operation because there's a `withContext` somewhere on that call path.

Let me also add a warning about a very typical misuse of the coroutine APIs: you almost never need `async-await`. Use it only for the cases where you want to truly run it "in the background" while you continue to perform other stuff in your current context. In simpler terms, you should never write

```
val result = async { calculation() }.await()
```

Instead you should write

```
val result = withContext(myThreadPool) { calculation() }
```

Comment: So if I have some functions which are asynchronous and `suspend`ing (the one with `suspendCoroutine`), it's ok to mark all the functions that call this function also as `suspend`?

Comment: Yes, and when you call such functions you'll get an indicator on the left gutter in IDEA so you know where the "interruptions" are in your code.